# Django not working on Wing IDE

Tags: python, django, wing-ide

- Platform: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2
- Wing IDE version 4.1.3-1
- Created a project using instructions from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).
- Tried to add that project by following the instructions [here](http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/django).
- Below are the screen shots of what Wing IDE says when I try to configure.

[image: Configuring Django]

[image]

The error message says:

> Django Files Not Found.  Please add your Django project directory to your Wing IDE Project then try again.  This command requires that the files manage.py and settings.py can be found in the project.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your files to the project first.  Or, it may be you're using Django 1.4 (the development version) which currently isn't supported.